# Facing issue while reading stdin in node

Tags: javascript

I just registered in `HackerEarth` and trying to solve the first basic problem: `Monk and rotation`. When I am running the code by entering single input it works fine but when I submit the solution it does not work.

https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/codemonk/

`It seems I am reading the input incorrectly`

Can someone please help.

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("utf-8");
var stdin_input = "";
 
process.stdin.on("data", function (input) {
    stdin_input += input;                               // Reading input from STDIN
});

process.stdin.on("end", function () {
    let lines = stdin_input.split('\n');
    let len = lines.length;
    let inputArr = [];
    
    const numberTestCase = lines[0]

    const output = new Array()
    
    for (i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
      let lineInput = lines[i].split(' ');
      let noOfElement = 0;
      let stepRotation = 0;
      let skipLineUpto = 0;
      let inputData = false;
      
      if (lineInput.length === 2) {
        inputData = true;
        noOfElement = lineInput[0]
        stepRotation = lineInput[1]

        skipLineUpto = parseInt(i) + 2;
      }
      
      if (inputData) {
        let stringOfArray = lines[i + 1];
        
        let arrayData = stringOfArray.split(' ');
        
        let mod = 0
        mod = stepRotation % noOfElement;

        if (mod != 0) {
          let unReversedArray = arrayData.splice(-mod);
          let ff = unReversedArray.concat(arrayData)
          inputArr.push(ff.join(' '))
        } else {
          let ff = arrayData
          console.log(ff.join(' '))
          inputArr.push(ff.join(' '))
        }
      }
      
    }
    main(inputArr)
});

function main(input) {
    process.stdout.write(input.join("\n"));       // Writing output to STDOUT
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you submit you can see why your code is not valid.

Your solution is for when scenarios where input is 3 lines (1 test case), like in their example, but you can see their test cases where they have inputs of multiple lines (T test cases).

Without any prototype method something like this would work (not working because time exceeded):

```
let lines = stdin_input.split('\n');
let loops = lines[0];

for(i = 1; i < lines.length; i+=2) {        
    let steps = lines[i].split(' ')[1];
    let arr = lines[i+1].split(' ');        
    
    for (j = 0; j < steps; j++) {
        var x = arr[arr.length-1], i;
        for (k = arr.length-1; k > 0; k--) {
            arr[k] = arr[k-1];
        }
        arr[0] = x;
    }
    
    main(arr);
}
```

With [pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) and [unshift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) only one test case is failing due to time exceeded but should get you close to the final solution:

```
let lines = stdin_input.split('\n');
let loops = lines[0];

for(i = 1; i < lines.length; i+=2) {        
    let steps = lines[i].split(' ')[1];
    let arr = lines[i+1].split(' ');        
    
    for (j = 0; j < steps; j++) {
        arr.unshift(arr.pop());
    }
    
    main(arr);
}
```